how to install and configure fltk 1.3.9 with visual studio 2022
I am new to C++ coding, studying independently from programming principles and practicing Bjarne Strostrup, when I got to the chapter on GUI I had a great frustration trying to install and configure FLTK, I spent the last couple of days trying to find a method that works but I almost always hit a snag, so I hope that someone would perhaps describe a webpage or give a detailed answer on dealing with this issue.
Thank you in advance.
I have looked on many webpages but it's either dealing with older versions or the explanations are vague_ at least considering my current programming knowledge.

Use Microsoft's vcpkg: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg

i used this but after cloning the repo to my pc and running the bootstrap the created application crashes or the window closes immediately @drescherjm

Could be your caused from your antivirus. Some AV may not like the telemetry in vcpkg. You can disable that but I don't remember the command. Could also be Dll Hell

Related to an AV problem: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/7240

@drescherjm unfortunately stopped my antivirus and still facing the same issue

Have you tried .\boostrap-vcpkg.bat -disableMetrics to bootstrap?

Your welcome! I am happy I was able to help.
